# Number of received messages from a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a test for chat client-server application and I create 10 sockets -each one of them sends a message to the other 9,which triggers the server to create 10 threads via an ExecutorService and send the messages.It takes some time for all the 10*9=90 messages to get sent,however how can I validate that all 10 threads have completed this job (the threads are not terminated they keep running).I was wondering if it is possible the total amount of lines received from a socket and wait on that condition until each socket reaches 9 received messages,if not how can I do it?Also I should not modify the client and chat code ,however I am free to write anything in the test ,here is how I create the 10 sockets and send message to the server which was started ofcourse :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
        allsockets.add(socket);
        final PrintWriter stream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        stream.println("someMessage");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a specialized problem, but given the information which you've provided, it may be worthwhile to use a `volatile` variable.

```
public static volatile int messagesReceived = 0;
```

The use of the keyword `volatile` means that the JVM uses a [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science))
 to ensure only one thread may modify the variable at one time.

Then, each socket should increment this `messagesReceived` variable once they complete their job. Once the `messagesReceived` variable reaches 10, or the number of threads that you've spawned, then you know for sure that they have all done that job.

```
//Your initialization here.
while (messagesReceived < threadCount){
    Thread.wait(100);
}
//All threads have done the job.
```

However, depending on your implementation of the sockets, it may be necessary to allow them access to a public mutator method that increments the counter variable.